# How to create a mysql db with a Knex migrator CLI command?

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I have a knex powered app that once I clone from github, I can run `yarn migrate:latest` to get the database up to date.

The problem is, in some cases, like a new developer, the database might not yet exist.

What is the right way to first create the database? Do I need to do that outside of KNEX or is there a KNEX CLI/Migration type of commend for this need?

Comment: easiest way, create database externally. If you like to do it on migration, you have to create migration file which should be the first file on migration folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not supported (knex 0.14.2). You need to create database + db users in advance. If you like to have node library helping in that `knex-db-manager` is knex based helper lib for database management like creating DBs and db owner user etc.